# Three.js Load Texture from adjacent file

Tags: javascript, image, three.js, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am working on a `three.js` project and I am trying to load a new Texture but I get `cross-origin` errors.

This works fine when switching to `localhost` but I also need this to work with `static HTML`.

I tried doing this but I still get the same error

```
function getImage(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.setAttribute("src", path);
            image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            image.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            });
            image.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                reject();
            });
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: With `static HTML`, do you mean accessing the page with a `file://` url? In that case you should read this: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-run-thing-locally

Comment: This is pretty much the same as placing it `wwwroot`. I was wondering if there is a way to solve it using pure javascript (without using a server or changing chrome properties)

Comment: Very likely not I'm afraid, as this is a mitigation against all sorts of attacks. If you need to have it working with a plain html-file you might have success inlining the images as `data:`-urls. You can try adding all required images with urls to the html-file (with `display:none`) and running https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-inline to do the inlining